# How can I have a username shorter than 4 characters?

Tags: members, users

I am trying to register a member with a two character username. Is this a possibility? I'd imagine I would need to hack the core, but is this a good idea? Where would I even get started with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, not long ago this would require a core hack.

Not sure exactly when this was fixed, but anyway these days you can add the following to your config.php file:

```
$config['un_min_len'] = 2; // allow a username w/only two characters
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override minimum username length with a config variable. You can also change the minimum password length too, but I suggest not:

```
$config['un_min_len'] = '2';
$config['pw_min_len'] = '5';
```